# Ajax: replace the content of the container vs load in other div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an ajax website. The intuitive way seems to be to use the jquery .html() method to replace the content of the container by new content.

However consider that user may visit A and then B and then A again, the second manipulation of reloading A seems unnecessary.

Another way occurs to me is to load the ajax content in a new div and somehow hide the original content. However it seems quite manual to me and I wonder is there a good framework or plugins to better handle this. And would there be performance issue in this case since dom elements keep growing?

Answer (score 1):

you can cache Ajax requests, so client javascript won't request server every time when you need a content. Eg. in jQuery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
```

Caching requests is actually default setting in jQuery so it caches responses all the time.

Comment: Google Chrome seems not to cache ajax contents, but IE10 does by default.

Answer (score 0):

In our use of jQuery, Google Chrome seems not to cache ajax contents, but IE10 really does by default.

To avoid the double loading of a dynamic content in general, we use a raw method like this for a div id="mydiv":

```
if($("#mydiv").get(0).loaded)
{
}
else
{
  $("#mydiv").get(0).loaded = true;
  //
  // here we load ajax content for mydiv:
  //
  ...
}
```

**loaded** is a user added JavaScript property of the persistent DOM element object of mydiv, not the temporary jQuery object.